# Mobile Table crashes IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

So I'm pulling my hair out over an IE9 bug that causes the browser to crash.  I have a table that I am reformatting for small screen devices using media queries.  It's some pretty slick coding, but in IE9 when I rescale the browser window larger than the media query it crashes IE9.  Seems to do it when you try taking CSS away from it but not when adding it maybe?

I posted my source [code here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nj7zb/3/). Try rescaling it in IE9.

I updated my source and narrowed it down to the [what is causing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Nj7zb/22/).

The HTML...

```
<table width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><a href="#">Detail 1</a></th>
<th><a href="#">Detail 2</a></th>
<th><a href="#">Detail 3</a></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td data-label="Detail 1: ">Detail 1 Here</td>
<td data-label="Detail 2: ">Detail 2 Here</td>
<td data-label="Detail 3: ">Detail 3 Here</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td data-label="Detail 1: ">Detail 1 Here</td>
<td data-label="Detail 2: ">Detail 2 Here</td>
<td data-label="Detail 3: ">Detail 3 Here</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td data-label="Detail 1: ">Detail 1 Here</td>
<td data-label="Detail 2: ">Detail 2 Here</td>
<td data-label="Detail 3: ">Detail 3 Here</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS...

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
TABLE TBODY {float:left}
TABLE TBODY TR {float:left}
TABLE TD {float:left}
TABLE TD:Before {float:left;content:attr(data-label)}
}
```

Comment: Post your markup, code and CSS in your question please.

Comment: Also, I'm not able to replicate the error using IE9.

Comment: Scratch that, if I try to resize the iframe in the jsFiddle, it crashes IE9 sure as the night is dark.

Comment: I know. It is really strange.  It seems to happen when taking CSS away that was previously added via a media query.

Comment: OK, narrowed it down to an issue with floating table elements and adding content via CSS.  No solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, well one fix seems to be adding float:left to the TABLE tag.  I don't really want to float the table so I'm going to keep looking for other fixes.

Comment: OK, I tried replacing float:left with the Nicolas Gallagher's [Micro Clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) and it worked in the example above, but when I added it to my full code it choked on the border-collapse:collapse;margin:24px 0; I have applied to the table.  http://jsfiddle.net/8xTPq/1/

Comment: Well it is hard to pin down exactly what triggers the problem, but it seems to center around the use of floats within a table, not clearing parent items within the table and the use of :before and content: to generate dynamic titles.  You can see the code breaking here...http://jsfiddle.net/JKtfs/10/  and see it working here... http://jsfiddle.net/JKtfs/21/

Comment: For those interested here is my final code with styles... http://jsfiddle.net/Nj7zb/28/

Comment: I am having a similar problem but unable to solve it yet. It does seem related to switching between float:left and float:none on a media query on td/th elements. The issue for me is if I pull out the table code it works ok but when part of the rest of the page it crashes. Do you know of an alternative to using floats to make IE9 display block TD/TH

Comment: No. It was the only thing that seemed to work in my tests and I'm not sure it even works on windows mobile.  I'm thinking about using JS to swap out table tags with divs the next time I have to code something like this.